# Sign of gravitational acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, potential-energy, conventions

The gravitational potential energy comes from the formula $mgh$ where $g$ is always $>0$.
But when we get to choose it's sign? I figured out, it really depends on what you choose as positive axis for the movement, where you put your starting point. To be more specific, I came across this equation for x-axis acceleration: $a=g\sin(20)$

What should I consider $g$ to be? Positive or negative? I know that it should be negative because it actually slows down the object (for my specific problem), but some formulas just require the magnitute of that value. This is more of a general question:bthe gravitational force is $F=mg$, we never ended up with a negative force, so why will $g$ in that equation (which came from the component of gravitational force) be negative?

Comment: Where did you come across a =g sin (20) for x-axis acceleration? Clearly the x-axis cannot be perpendicular to the direction of the gravitational force since the acceleration would be zero.

Comment: This can all be solved using vectors instead of scalars with a minus sign in front. Which are just the components of a vector

Answer (score 1):

> The gravitational potential energy comes from the formula mgh where g is always >0.

I agree with the sentiment and practice that $g$ is always positive, because $g$ is the *magnitude* of a vector. If we assume that $\vec{g}$ is the gravitational field of a mass, that vector always points toward the center of mass. Applying this to Earth, $\vec{g}$ points *down* (that's the definition of *down*) and at the surface is about $9.8$ m/s$^2$ *down*. The magnitude is positive, the direction is down.

The big questions for you are *what is h  and is it positive or negative*?

In its traditional use $h$ is the position of some object *up* from some reference point. In other words, $h$ is a vertical location which is positive when you move opposite gravity from a pre-defined arbitrary zero height. With that perspective, $mgh$ gives you the **change in potential energy** ($\Delta PE$) from the arbitrary height. And it's okay to move below the zero height (so $h$ becomes negative) and you get a negative potential energy, because the change is ultimately what's important. But you must use *up* as the positive motion and position change direction, and $g > 0$.

A better formula would be $$\Delta PE = mg \left(y_{\mathrm{final}}-y_{\mathrm{initial}}\right)$$
where the positive $y$ direction is opposite gravity (or up). [Warning: if $h$ is large compared to Earth's radius, this formula doesn't work.]

If you are using $g$ as part of an acceleration or force problem, you must consider the *direction* of that force or acceleration. For example, if you choose *up* as positive $y$ direction, and the force is down with a magnitude of $mg\sin\theta$, then you will have $$F_y = mg\sin\theta (-\hat{y})$$

Notice that there is a negative sign, but $g$ is still a positive value. The negative sign comes from the direction part of the vector. $g$ is a magnitude.

What your question illustrates is the danger in "equation hunting" without considering definitions and limitations. It's probably caused by either 1) the book you are using, or 2) your instructor, or both.  It doesn't matter which. You should always seek to understand the origin of an equation, the definitions of the quantities within it, and the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational potential energy is actually derived from the universal law of gravitation.
$$F=\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
$$\text {dU}=-F\text {dx}$$
$$\text {dU}=-\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\text {dx}$$
$$U=-\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r}$$

As you can see, the gravitational potential energy is always negative as distance can never be negative. This is because the energy is maximum (zero) at infinity.

The formula $U=mgh$ is only valid when **very** close to the surface of earth and this considers the energy at the surface to be zero. In reality, all formulae are in vector form and do account for the direction not just magnitude. If you take proper sign conventions $g$ will always be negative and the answer will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The constant $g$ is defined to be positive. Here's how it is defined.
Newton's gravitational law says that the magnitude of the force between two point-like masses is given by
$F=G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$ , where $m_i$'s are the masses of the objects,  $r$ is the distance between them and $G$ is the [gravitational constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).

Whenever we analyze objects on Earth (I.e. those whose distance $r$ from the surface of the Earth to their location is much smaller than the radius of the Earth) we simplify Newton's gravitational law by absorbing $G, r$ and one of the masses (which corresponds to the mass of the Earth) into a single constant that we call "$g$", which is defined as:
$g\equiv \frac{G M_E}{R_E^2}$, where $M_E$ and $R_E$ are the mass and radius of the Earth, respectively, and $G$ is the gravitational constant. Once you plug in the actual values of these three constants you will find that $g=9.81>0$